# Unable to plot a bar chart using my dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the below dataframe into a barchart:

```
        JP_genre JP_sales
0         Action   159.95
1      Adventure    52.07
2       Fighting    87.35
3           Misc   107.76
4       Platform   130.77
5         Puzzle    57.31
6         Racing    56.69
7   Role-Playing   352.31
8        Shooter    38.28
9     Simulation    63.70
10        Sports   135.37
11      Strategy    49.46
```

When I put in the following code:

```
JP_df.plot(x = 'JP_genre', y = 'JP_sales', kind= 'bar')
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: no numeric data to plot
```

Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Could it be that the JP_sales column is string instead of float?

Comment: I have recreated the excel sheet and tried your function and it worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your code. Here is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

JP_df = pd.read_csv("temp.csv")
print(JP_df)
JP_df.plot(x='JP_genre', y='JP_sales', kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

After saving the data you pasted above in `temp.csv`, and it ran perfectly.

What you could be wrong is that the type of the values of column `JP_sales` in your DataFrame are not numeric values (i.e. they could be saved as strings).
You can try casting the second column to floats before calling `.plot()` like this:

```
JP_df = JP_df.astype({"JP_genre": str, "JP_sales": float})
JP_df.plot(x='JP_genre', y='JP_sales', kind='bar')
plt.show()
```